# Using dojox Uploader in Dojo >= 1.7 (AMD)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo

I'm just trying to incorporate `dojox/form/Uploader` into my application, which is using Dojo 1.9.2 (AMD). The documentation http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/Uploader.html#dojox-form-uploader is quite outdated, for example Dojo screamed not to import `dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash` through `require`, because it's already built-in, so my example after adaptations is looking like that (**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4atgbe87/1/)**):

```html
<form class="claro">
  <div id="uploader"></div>
</form>
```

```javascript
require(['dojox/form/Uploader',  "dojo/domReady!"], function(Uploader){
  var u = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    label: "Select files",
    multiple: true,
    uploadOnSelect: false,
    url: "/my/rest/file/upload",
  }, "uploader");
})
```

However, the problem is, that nothing happens whel I click the 'Select files' button. Neither on Firefox, nor on IE 11.

What I need to do to use Uploader component with newer version of Dojo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Uploader widget is just declared. It needs to be instantiated. Add the following line after the declaration.

```
u.startup();
```

Now, the widget would work. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4atgbe87/2/)

```
require(['dojox/form/Uploader',  "dojo/domReady!"], function(Uploader){
  var u = new dojox.form.Uploader({
    label: "Select files",
    multiple: true,
    uploadOnSelect: false,
    url: "/my/rest/file/upload",
  }, "uploader");
  u.startup();
});
```